# not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I'm struggling with this error when I change the statement from order to group, the goal it's to get the sum f all records that met the query.

I've two tables, ServiceConsumer_T and ServiceUsage_t, in the ServiceConsumer_t are all the consumer details:

```
ID                                      Name
032159DA-9BD6-49F0-8D12-5806DD17AE4B     40791010
05EECE4D-9E46-420A-9EE8-1605A34A1BE9     20002810
07C9EDB9-CF1C-4F32-83D5-4BE0293E626F     20019010
0AB09B43-F695-4314-9674-A6B34254A1F0     20002700
0FE8F929-D33C-4CA7-A0FA-0C804EDFE29C     20002210
```

in the ServiceUsage_t are the movements by customers:

```
CostCenterPath                          Cardinality
{032159DA-9BD6-49F0-8D12-5806DD17AE4B}  282
{032159DA-9BD6-49F0-8D12-5806DD17AE4B}  9
{032159DA-9BD6-49F0-8D12-5806DD17AE4B}  555
{05EECE4D-9E46-420A-9EE8-1605A34A1BE9}  200
{05EECE4D-9E46-420A-9EE8-1605A34A1BE9}  200
{05EECE4D-9E46-420A-9EE8-1605A34A1BE9}  3
{05EECE4D-9E46-420A-9EE8-1605A34A1BE9}  3
{07C9EDB9-CF1C-4F32-83D5-4BE0293E626F}  1500
{07C9EDB9-CF1C-4F32-83D5-4BE0293E626F}  1
{07C9EDB9-CF1C-4F32-83D5-4BE0293E626F}  1
{07C9EDB9-CF1C-4F32-83D5-4BE0293E626F}  243
```

This is the query that I'm utilizing:

```
Select ServiceConsumer_T.Name, ServiceUsage_T.Cardinality from ServiceConsumer_T    
left join ServiceUsage_T
on ServiceConsumer_T.ID=ServiceUsage_T.CostCenterPath

order by ServiceConsumer_T.Name
```

And I get all records ordered by Name,  but when I change from order to group I get the error:

> Column 'ServiceUsage_T.Cardinality' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2):

If you group by a column, all other must be aggregated. You want to sum, so use that aggregate function

```
Select c.Name, sum(u.Cardinality)
from ServiceConsumer_T  c   
left join ServiceUsage_T u on c.ID = u.CostCenterPath
group by c.Name
```

Comment: Hi Jurgen,Thank you very much for your promt reply, it fullfit my requirements.